# For merging 2 sorted linked list in reverse order I am getting AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' for some of the testcases. Why

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list

I am looking at the [Merge 2 sorted linked list in reverse order](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/merge-2-sorted-linked-list-in-reverse-order/1) practice challenge on Geeks for Geeks:

> Given two linked lists of size `N` and `M`, which are sorted in non-decreasing order. The task is to merge them in such a way that the resulting list is in decreasing order.
>
> #### Input:
>
> First line of input contains number of testcases T. For each testcase, first line of input conatains [sic] length of both linked lists N and M respectively. Next two lines contains N and M elements of two linked lists.
>
> #### Output:
>
> For each testcase, print the merged linked list which is in non-increasing order.
>
> #### User Task:
>
> The task is to complete the function `mergeResult()` which takes reference to the heads of both linked list and returns the pointer to the merged linked list.

### My Approach

I am trying to first merge the list in ascending order and then reverse it.
It is working for most of the test cases but failing for few with error:-

> line 21, in mergeResult
>
> ```
> p3=p3.next
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

```
def mergeResult(h1,h2):
    p1=h1
    p2=h2
    node=Node(-1)
    p3=node
    while p1!=None and p2!=None:
        if p1.data<p2.data:
            p3.next=p1
            p1=p1.next
        elif p2.data<p1.data:
            p3.next=p2
            p2=p2.next
        p3=p3.next
    if p1!=None:
        p3.next=p1
    if p2!=None:
        p3.next=p2
    head=node.next
    curr=head
    prev=None
    next=None
    while curr:
        next=curr.next
        curr.next=prev
        prev=curr
        curr=next
    head=prev
    return head
```

What am I doing  wrong here? Is there any other approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
elif p2.data<p1.data:
```

There shouldn't be a condition here, as you want to deal with *all remaining cases*. Right now you don't treat the case where `p2.data` is equal to `p1.data`. So change the above line to:

```
else:
```

This will fix the issue.

### Alternative

There is a shorter way to achieve the result: instead of reversing the list in a second phase, insert the nodes in reverse order directly. That way you can deal with the job in one loop instead of two. You should then continue the loop as long as one of the references is not `None`, so the `while` condition becomes an `or`. Then in the `if` condition you need to consider that one of the two could be `None`. Finally, you don't really need to introduce `p1` and `p2` variables: just use the already given `h1` and `h2`.

This solution also doesn't need the temporary "sentinel" node (the one with value -1).

```
def mergeResult(h1,h2):
    result = None
    while h1 or h2:
        if not h2 or (h1 is not None and h1.data < h2.data):
            h1.next, result, h1 = result, h1, h1.next
        else:
            h2.next, result, h2 = result, h2, h2.next
    return result
```

So here `h1` (or `h2`) is *prepended* to the current result list. After it is prepended, the result reference is put to that prepended node. The multiple assignment is such that `h1` (or `h2`) will still walk to the (original) *next* node, before that node's `next` reference is adjusted. You can of course also do this with separate assignments, but then you need a temporary variable:

```
def mergeResult(h1,h2):
    result = None
    while h1 or h2:
        if not h2 or (h1 is not None and h1.data < h2.data):
            nxt = h1.next
            h1.next = result
            result = h1
            h1 = nxt
        else:
            nxt = h2.next
            h2.next = result
            result = h2
            h2 = nxt
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop of mergeResult, you need to check whether p1.data == p2.data. Currently, you are not checking this, so when p1.data == p2.data, p3.next is not set (and thus maintains its default value of None). This means that p3 gets set to None, and as the error shows, p3.next (i.e. None.next) does not work.